# How to add missing key to dictionary in ansible

Tags: json, ansible

I have variable testing with example value like this:

```
- testing: 
  - failed: "yes"
    msg: "anothermessage"
  - results:
      - url: "ip:port"
        json:
          messages: 
            - message: "yepp"
              severity: "ok"
    failed: "yes"
    msg: "ikan"
  - failed: "no"
    msg: "anothermessageyeay"
```

the value of testing might be different and there are times where the key results in the structure missing like the example. how to add the key of results with some string so i can map it?

I expect the output to be like this:

```
- testing: 
  - results: "not exist"
    failed: "yes"
    msg: "anothermessage"
  - results:
      - url: "ip:port"
        json:
          messages: 
            - message: "yepp"
              severity: "ok"
    failed: "yes"
    msg: "ikan"
  - results: "not exist"
   failed: "no"
    msg: "anothermessageyeay"
```

Comment: Fix the YAML syntax (" is missing in the first results).  What value of results would you like to add? `not` or `not exist`?

Comment: sorry, i mean not exist, i edited my previous questions

Answer (score 0):

The expression below

```yaml
results_default:
  results: not exist
testing2: "{{ [results_default]|
              product(testing)|
              map('combine')|
              list }}"
```

---

Optionally, use the template below

```yaml
testing2: |
  {% filter from_yaml %}
  {% for x,y in [results_default]|product(testing) %}
  - {{ x|combine(y) }}
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfilter %}
```

---

add the default attribute *results* to the dictionaries

```yaml
testing2:
  - failed: 'yes'
    msg: anothermessage
    results: not exist
  - failed: 'yes'
    msg: ikan
    results:
    - json:
        messages:
        - message: yepp
          severity: ok
      url: ip:port
  - failed: 'no'
    msg: anothermessageyeay
    results: not exist
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    testing: 
      - failed: "yes"
        msg: "anothermessage"
      - results:
          - url: "ip:port"
            json:
              messages: 
                - message: "yepp"
                  severity: "ok"
        failed: "yes"
        msg: "ikan"
      - failed: "no"
        msg: "anothermessageyeay"

    results_default:
      results: not exist
    testing2: "{{ [results_default]|
                  product(testing)|
                  map('combine')|
                  list }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: testing2
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i localhost, pb.yml

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  testing2:
  - failed: 'yes'
    msg: anothermessage
    results: not exist
  - failed: 'yes'
    msg: ikan
    results:
    - json:
        messages:
        - message: yepp
          severity: ok
      url: ip:port
  - failed: 'no'
    msg: anothermessageyeay
    results: not exist

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: i got this as a result:

"testing2": "<generator object do_map at 0x7f71ed6f1ba0>"

Comment: Please upgrade to a version of ansible > 2.9 (which has been deprecated for years). In the mean time as a workarround, add `| list` at the end of the above jinja2 expression.

Comment: I updated the answer with the filter *list* in the pipe.

Comment: - set_fact:
        results_default:
          results: not exist
        testing2: "{{ [results_default]|
                      product(testing)|
                      map('combine')|
                      list }}"

i try this code an get this result:
  "msg": "|combine expects dictionaries, got (AnsibleUndefined, {'failed': 'yes', 'msg': 'anothermessage'})",

my Ansible Automation Platform Controller version is 4.3.5

Comment: I added the complete playbook.

Comment: im sorry but get error

  "msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ [results_default]| product(testing)| map('combine')| list }}'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleFilterError'>, original message: |combine expects dictionaries, got ({'results': 'not exist'}, {'failed': 'yes', 'msg': 'anothermessage'})"

Comment: This older version of the filter *combine* needs the syntax `x|combine(y)`. The syntax `(x, y)|combine` was added later. You've been already told to upgrade. If you can't upgrade use the template I added.